# Table in cvline using moderncv

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, moderncv

I would like to create in my CV, using `moderncv`, a table with two columns.
It should look like:

```
-------- Experience
          * Item 1          x
                            x
                            x
```

and it should be below the text of `\section`.

I tried the following code, but from a reason I do not understand I get an error

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{casual}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths

\firstname{first}
\familyname{last}

\begin{document}
 \section{Experience}
    %\cvline{}{\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \cvline{}{\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item Item 1
                    \end{itemize} & x \\
                                  & x \\
                                  & x
                \end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
after changing `\cvline{}{\begin{tabular}{ll}` to `\cvline{}{\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}` the error disappeared, but `Item 1` was not at the same line with `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three solutions that achieve output similar to what you want in different ways. I couldn't figure how to get rid of the whitespace before `itemize` in a `tabular`, but that seems to be a general issue and not something specific to `moderncv`.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{casual}

\usepackage{geometry}

\firstname{first} \familyname{last}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\section{Experience}

% This seems to be the best solution to me

\cvlistitem{\parbox[t]{5cm}{Item 1}
\parbox[t]{5cm}{
\lipsum[66]
x \\
x \\
}}

% This one works if you really want to keep the table setup.
% \labelitemi is the macro LaTeX uses to insert the itemize bullet.
% The text block is a little further left because the bullet + following
% space are part of the 5cm.

\cvline{}{
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\labelitemi~Item 1 & \lipsum*[66] \\
                   & x \\
                   & x \\
\end{tabular}}

% This version is a little more idiosyncratic to moderncv's layout with
% a "label" in the left column. Note, however, how the bullets don't line up.
% This doesn't happen with the other solutions.
% If you don't want the paragraphs to be as wide, you can replace \linewidth
% with something like 5cm, of course.

\cvline{\labelitemi~Foo}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
x \\
x }}
\cvline{\labelitemi~Item 1}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
\lipsum[66]
x \\
x }}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]